# FaceAlign AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Face Align and getting the following error for every image:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I interpret this to mean that my code is expecting an image object and instead receiving a string, correct?

The offending code:

```
def getAligns(self,
                img,
                use_cnn = False,
                savepath = None,
                return_info = False):
    """
    get face alignment picture
    :param img: original BGR image or a path to it
    :param use_cnn: using CNN to extract aligned faces, if set, dlib 
                    be compiled with cuda support
    :param savepath: savepath, format "xx/xx/xx.png"
    :param return_info: if set, return face positinos [(x, y, w, h)] 
    :return: aligned faces, (opt) rects
    """
    print(img.shape)
    if type(img) == str:
      try:
          img = cv2.imread(img)
          img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      except:
          shutil.copy2(img, 'temp.jpg')
          img = cv2.imread('temp.jpg')
          img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
          os.remove('temp.jpg')
```

Relevant code from Align_Faces:

```
  if clean: clear_dir(config.aligned)
  os.chdir(config.labeled)
  jobs = glob.glob("*.jpg")
  print(len(jobs))
##  # un-parallel
  for picname in jobs:
      print(picname)
      aligned = FL.getAligns(picname)
      if len(aligned) != 1:
        print(config.aligned)
        print(picname)
        print(aligned[0])
        return cv2.imwrite(config.aligned + picname, aligned[0])
```

Full output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at your data flow:

```
jobs = glob.glob("*.jpg")

##  # un-parallel
for picname in jobs:
    print(picname)
    aligned = FL.getAligns(picname)

def getAligns(self,
            img,
            use_cnn = False,
            savepath = None,
            return_info = False):
    print(img.shape)
```

Your posted output shows that you've maintained the file name as a string `0_0_ErinMurphy.jpg`, and passed that string into `getAligns`.  A string has no `shape` attribute.  You've missed a conversion step, such as reading in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the string with the image name to the function and then asking what is the shape of the string.

```
print(picname)
```

returns `0_0_ErinMurphy.jpg` which is a string.

You need to import the image and then convert it to the pixels so that you can read its shape.